# Single public IP routed to multiple internal IPs by port

Tags: cisco-asa, dnat

We have a network setup with a Cisco ASA 5515,IPS firewall running ASA 9.8(4)29 and ASDM 7.12(2).  I have several rules setup to route public ip addresses and specific ports to specific internal hosts.  However, I am having trouble sharing a public ip address with two internal hosts based on port number.  We are trying to share a public ip address among several hosts to provide remote desktop access.  For now, I edited the port numbers on the hosts to match the inbound ports.

My current setup:

```
<public ip 1> port 9001 ==> 10.10.100.31 9001
<public ip 2> port 9002 ==> 10.10.100.32 9002
```

What I would like to do is:

```
<public ip 1> port 9001 ==> 10.10.100.31 3389  
<public ip 1> port 9002 ==> 10.10.100.32 3389
```

Every time I tried to set this up I got an exception stating I was overlapping a translation.  I am assuming I am not setting up the inbound part of the rule correctly and the same public ip is causing the issue.  I have done this many times on a Sonicwall device but our datacenter only provides Cisco.  I am editing the firewall using ASDM rather than CLI.  I am using the Public Server screen to setup the single ip mappings with no problem.  I would appreciate any advice on how to set this up.

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: Please add what's relevant of the configuration to your question for us to see. The ASA isn't complaining without a reason.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into VPN to secure RDP access, removing the need for any port forwarding.

Comment: Try deleting the previous translation first.

Comment: Like @Zac67 said, without seeing your config we're flying blind.  Please post a sanitized config so we can figure out what the problem is.